# Can we stringify a Javascript array in same way PHP implode('separator', $array) does?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, implode

I am having a JavaScript array and I want to convert this array into string with a separator, in a way **PHP implode** does.

e.g.

```
var daysArr = [];
daysArr.push('monday');
daysArr.push('tuesday');
```

I want to get "monday*tuesday"

How can we achieve this?

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this

```
daysArr.join('*');
```

---

NameOfArray.join('separator');

Comment: I tried doing that, but there is a constraint in place which says you can accept answer after 5 minutes

Comment: Hmm, how strange. Probably a good thing in case better answers appear.

Answer (score 1):

[array.join(separator)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = "1";
arr[1] = "2";

alert(arr.join("*"));
```

Demo [example](http://jsfiddle.net/a2xn5/).

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript function join

```
daysArr.join('*');
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should do it

```
<script>
var daysArr = [];
daysArr.push('monday');
daysArr.push('tuesday');

function implode(arr, sep) {
    //Output string
    output = '';
    //Counter
    j = 1;
    for (i in arr) {
        //Append
        output += arr[i];
        //Add seperater if not the last item
        if (j != arr.length) {
            output += sep;
        }
        j++;
    }
    //Return output
    return output;
}

alert(implode(daysArr, ','));
</script>
```

Comment: Oops, forgot about the join function!

Comment: Yup, we need not write this big heap of code, if it offered as default. Good try though